# When the GridView scrolls, it changes CheckBox Selections

Tags: android, gridview, checkbox, scroll

Accualy i read all posts but i cant solution my problem. And i need help.

I have got gridview. I am filling grids a baseadapter. My grids has got ImageViews and CheckBoxes. I am LongTouching any grid and checking CheckBox. All is done here.

But when i scroll the gridview all selections changing. I try some solution from other posts but i can't fix problem.

Adapter GetView Method;

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View grid;

   if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mygrid, parent, false);
    } else 
    {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.imagepart);
    final CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)grid.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    ch.setTag(position);

    HashMap<String,String> tar;
    tar = data.get(position);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(tar.get(FragmentB.FOTOYOL),imageView);

    grid.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            CheckBox chh = (CheckBox)v.findViewWithTag(position);
            chh.setChecked(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return grid;
}
```

If I delete (convertView == null) line and remove else block then, checks not changing but when checkbox is going to unseen because of scroll, returning with scroll to that checkbox and it is unchecked. Not permanently checked.

I need big help. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the checked status with your backing data, not (only) in the view. That means that the `OnLongClickListener` has to add an item to the `tar` map:

```
tar.put("checked", "true");
```

and the `getView(…)` method (outside the doubleclick listener) needs to initialize the checkbox from that data:

```
String checked = tar.get("checked");
grid.findViewWithTag(position).setChecked(
        checked != null && Boolean.getBoolean(checked)
    );
```

Note: you have to declare `tar` as `final` for it to be reachable inside the listener.

Comment: Can you explain more please ? Sorry.

Comment: GridView is designed to re-use views for efficiency. So for example, you may have 100 items of data but only 10 views can fit on the screen. If the view showing data item 1 scrolls off the screen at the top, that view is moved to the bottom and becomes `convertView` for item 11. All the data for item 1 is still in there, so you have to overwrite *all* of it to show data 11 correctly (i.e. you must clear the checkbox). When you scroll in the other direction, you want the checkboxes to be set as they were before scrolling, which is why you have to track the checked status in the data itself.

Comment: Thank you but i cant apply your code correcly. I am using tar map for only images. Must I assign a new "tar map" inside of clicklistener ? Can you update my code ? I m fighting this thing long time.. I am realy sorry because of your more exhausted ..

Comment: No, you must not assign a new tar map. The boolean value goes into the bit that's returned by `data.get(position)`, because that's where it has to come from when an item is scrolled back into view. I will not update your code for you, I think you need to do that yourself to really learn from your question.

Comment: I update my code like this but same error where is the wrong?
        
String checked = tar.get("checked");
        if (checked == "true")
        {
            CheckBox hh = (CheckBox)grid.findViewWithTag(position);
                    hh.setChecked(true);
        }

putting to tar check boolean inside of listener like you said;

tar.put("checked", "true");

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with Barend help;

I changed the getview method like this;

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View grid;

            grid = new View(mContext);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mygrid, parent, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.imagepart);
        final CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)grid.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        ch.setTag(position);

        final HashMap<String,String> tar;
        tar = data.get(position);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(tar.get(FragmentB.FOTOYOL), imageView);

        String checked = tar.get("checked");
        if (checked == "true")
        {
            CheckBox hh = (CheckBox)grid.findViewWithTag(position);
                    hh.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (checked == "false")
        {
            CheckBox hh = (CheckBox)grid.findViewWithTag(position);
            hh.setChecked(false);
        }

        grid.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                CheckBox chh = (CheckBox)v.findViewWithTag(position);
                if (chh.isChecked())
                {
                    chh.setChecked(false);
                    tar.put("checked","false");
                }
                else
                {
                    chh.setChecked(true);
                    tar.put("checked", "true");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return grid;
    }
```